# csv manipulation in java

Tags: java, csv

I have this csv:

```
,,,,
,Bankleitzahlen,,,
,,,,
,Bank-leitzahl,Bezeichnung,PLZ,Ort
,10000000,Bundesbank,10591,Berlin
,10010010,Postbank,10916,Berlin
,10010111,SEB,10789,Berlin
```

I want to show in console this file but without the first column and without the three first lines. I managed to eliminate the lines, but i don't seem to find the way of deleting the first empty column.

This is the code that i have:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class csv {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String[]> objectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        String csvFile = "/_p/csv/src/ueberweisungen.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",w+,";

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            objectArrayList.add(country);
        }

        for (int i=3; i<objectArrayList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(objectArrayList.get(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to delete the first column?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
if(country.length > 1){
    objectArrayList.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(country, 1, country.length));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the empty column before you split the string.

```
line = line.replaceFirst(",","");

String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
objectArrayList.add(country);
```

If you want to dynamically replace any number of empty columns, you would need a more complex algorithm.